# SQL 3 AND PROBLEMS

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to update my data in my db but I run the my script Toad says that 0 rows updated even if my conditions are excatly true. What is the problem?

```
update CCB.CCB_PRICE_CAT_BALANCE_CAT set end_date =  (
    select  min(start_date) 
    from CCB.CCB_PRICE_CAT_BALANCE_CAT  
    where price_code ='XBG93MCM' 
        and balance_id = 'HS-XSOTHER' group by price_code), 
upd_user='caktas', 
upd_date=sysdate 
where  (price_code ='XBG93MCM' and balance_id = 'HS-XSOTHER') 
    and start_date = (
        select  min(start_date) 
        from CCB.CCB_PRICE_CAT_BALANCE_CAT  
        where price_code ='XBG93MCM' 
            and balance_id = 'HS-XSOTHER' 
        group by price_code);
```

Comment: Its not possible to tell without looking at data. Kindly post the data as well.

Comment: Am I dreaming or end_date could just be set to start_date? And the group by clause is useless.

Comment: One thing that's odd is the "GROUP BY" clause on the subqueries. What's your intent with that?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? What exactly does "SQL 3" mean?

Comment: yes I want to set start_date to end_date which has a min(start_date) data

Answer (score 0):

Isn't your query currently the same as:

```
update CCB.CCB_PRICE_CAT_BALANCE_CAT
set
    end_date = start_date
    , upd_user='caktas'
    , upd_date=sysdate 
where price_code ='XBG93MCM'
and balance_id = 'HS-XSOTHER'
and start_date = (
    select
        min(start_date) 
    from CCB.CCB_PRICE_CAT_BALANCE_CAT  
    where price_code ='XBG93MCM' 
    and balance_id = 'HS-XSOTHER' 

);
```

If so, can you check the value of `min(start_date)`?

Comment: the problem is same unfourtunaletly

Comment: I know, it's meant to help find the issue. Can you check the value of min(start_date)?